# How to edit the highlight color in PyCharm of a tag?

Tags: xml, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

I am using PyCharm to edit a XML file, and the highlight color of the tag is pretty uncomfortable.
The code is like:

```xml
<DumpRoot>

</DumpRoot>
```

And the effect is like:

[image: this]

How do I configure PyCharm so that I can change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation [Customize a color scheme](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#customize-color-scheme).

The color can be changed by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `General` `>` `Color Sheme` `>` `XML` and adjusting the color for `Matched Tag` in that window. As shown in the screenshot:

[image: IDE settings page]

Comment: Hi, the real answer is that I installed a plugin that caused the situation, but your solution it's the common one, so I will accept it anyway. Thanks a lot!